# application hangs on while (webClient.IsBusy)

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am creating an updater and it launches/reads files when its done using while like so,

```
while (webClient.IsBusy) { lbStat.Text = "Downloading: " + file; }
```

It doesn't display the Downloading: Filehere but it does download.
The download has a download bar how fast your downloading etc but will not show up because it hangs on while. 
Is there anything like while but does not hang?

Comment: you can fire an event to start it and fire an event to stop it, once the download is done

Comment: Example? Not sure what you mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are running a  time consuming work on your UI thread if you do that, your UI thread will block/freeze until that task completes.

I have used background worker in such scenarios .Here are few links that may help

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

[How to use a BackgroundWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker)