# Cancel button not working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating C#.net(4.0) application.This application is a **Console Application and I am creating a Window Form in this application with two button start and cancel**.

From the **main Function** I am calling the form :
      Application.Run(new Form());

Now the form contains two buttons :

- Start Button-On start button click I am doing some task.

  ```
    Task1();
    Task2();
  ```
- Cancel Button-On Cancel button click I want to terminate application.

  ```
    Application.Exit() //is called on Cancel Button click.
  ```

The problem is as I start the application and click cancel button application terminates, but when I press start button and then press cancel button the application doesn't terminate..

Comment: If those tasks use threads you should also stop them

Comment: Your tasks are performed on the UI thread, which means your button clicks aren't processed until the tasks finish. Take a look at the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker).

Comment: You should wait until the threads are finished doing their work. If you do want to immediately shutdown the application, use: `Environment.Exit(0);`

Comment: Thanks for the sugession.I got it, you all are correct.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg I used Enironment.Exit(0) but still same issue is there.I am not able to terminate application.

Comment: Please add comments so that I can find Solution..