# C# - VS2010: How to do some stuff and wait for some time without blocking the UI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a simple application, and I need to do some stuff, and update a progress bar. I do some stuff, wait for 1 second, and if the execution did OK, I increase a progress bar, do some other stuff, wait another second, and if OK, increase the progress bar, and so on, 7 times. By stuff, it means I'm connection to an electronic board via RS232, send some commands, it executes, and after 1 second I check if everyting did fine on the board. I need to wait 1 second for some analogic stuff on the board.

The problem is about waiting that one second. If I use Thread.Sleep(1000), the entire UI freezes (as expected) and the progress bar works in a "not synchronized" wait for the same reason.

My code is like:

```
progressBar1.Value = 0;

/* Do some stuff */
Thread.Sleep(1000);
/* Check the stuff */

progressBar1.Value = 1;

/* Do some stuff */
Thread.Sleep(1000);
/* Check the stuff */

progressBar1.Value = 2;

/* Do some stuff */
Thread.Sleep(1000);
/* Check the stuff */
```

and so on...  7 times.

The "stuff" are all different for every step.

Which is the best way to make my code to wait for 1 second?

Thanx for any help!!!

Comment: 1. Look at threading/background processes 2. *Why* do you want your code to wait for 1 second?

Comment: What type of application?  Winforms?  Console?  Web?

Comment: I don't know what the Thread.Sleep is for, but chances are that you may want to use a Timer + event handler instead.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) if your version of .NET Framework supports it. This is exactly the kind of problem the TPL was designed to solve. To do that, you would start an asynchronous Task, which is an encapsulation on top of the Thread class.

Conceptually, you should be creating a **new** thread for the connection to the RS232 board. Your main thread (UI thread) keeps executing and does not freeze the UI. If this is a Windows application, you should read more about multithreaded programming because using a single thread in a Windows application that needs to do many things "at once" will always cause blocking and freezing issues.

If your .NET Framework version does NOT support TPL, then you should use a class called BackgroundWorker. Here's a small example to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx

PS: My answer is based on the assumption that you are programming a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple, contrived WinForms example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProgressBar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task task1 = new Task(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); });
            Task task2 = new Task(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); });
            Task task3 = new Task(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); });
            Task task4 = new Task(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); });

            task1.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.Exception != null)
                    t.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                    {
                        //do something
                        return true;
                    });
                progressBar.Value = 25;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).ContinueWith((t) => task2.Start());


            task2.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.Exception != null)
                    t.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                    {
                        //do something
                        return true;
                    });
                progressBar.Value = 50;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).ContinueWith((t) => task3.Start());

            task3.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.Exception != null)
                    t.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                    {
                        //do something
                        return true;
                    });
                progressBar.Value = 75;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).ContinueWith((t) => task4.Start());

            task4.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                if (t.Exception != null)
                    t.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                    {
                        //do something
                        return true;
                    });
                progressBar.Value = 100;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            task1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, just create a task for each operation; then on the continuation of that task, check the [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) (this is very important, as if you don't check it and there is an exception, your program will crash when the task is garbage collected).  On the completion of that continuation, just fire the next task.  If you need to do UI access from one of the tasks, make sure that you invoke that task from the CurrentSynchronizationContext.