# How can I convert this to an asynchronous procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a loop I made like

```
        for(DateTime later = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5); DateTime.Now < later; Thread.Sleep(500))
        {

            // ... stuff
        }
```

and I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to convert that to a non-blocking way of doing stuff.

Comment: using a `for` loop for this is very werid. Make it a `while` loop and it will be much more obvious how to change it to asnyc. Also, the "best way" to make it async depends on what you are doing with `// ... stuff`, do you need to interact with the UI? do you need to do more things after the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way of doing so is to use a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspxhttp://) class and insert your function into its [RunWorkerAsynch/DoWork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Good examples are mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679044.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker).

alternatively you can run a separate thread. There are tons of articles about multi-threading in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Add a thread object and put the blocking loop inside it, like this:

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        for(DateTime later = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5); DateTime.Now < later; Thread.Sleep(500))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Other Thread: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Start);
        thread.Start(); 
    }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx for more info.

Here's a little example I made... http://rextester.com/QWMG44444 enjoy!