# When form’s owner is busy, form is busy too. But I don’t want that behavior

Tags: c#, forms

I am writing a macro for an application. I can get the window handle of the application so my macro form has an owner. So the windows of application and my form are paired.

My macro creates a list of tasks and one by one sends that to the application. So my form is user responsive when working. The application does long computing (It’s CAM software) and I added a button that can stops sending tasks to the application.

It’s work good, when my form has no owner, but then windows aren’t paired. 
When windows are paired, the busy status is copying to my form. So clicking to my stop button is clumsy.

Has anybody some suggestion, how a form can have an owner, but only for pairing? 
(By pairing I mean: When I click on the window of application, my form is binged front too and vice versa.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker

Comment: Here is a how to from MSDN on this very topic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thank for a suggestion. It’s a topic, that I am going to explore. 
Now I have an idea that could solve my problem. Can I someway prohibit a busy type cursor in my form?