# How to make label text refresh?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class for refreshing the text of a label:

```
class GUIDisplayer:IOutputter
    {
        Label label;
        public GUIDisplayer(Label label)
        {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public void display(string text)
        {
            label.Text = text;
            label.Refresh();
        }

    }
```

An instance of this class gets passed to another class in my Windows Forms app, where I use it for showing progress during a For loop:

```
public class BatchConverter
    {

        IOutputter outputter;

        public BatchConverter(IOutputter outputter)
        {
            this.outputter = outputter;
        }

        public bool convertFiles(List<FileTransferData> fileTransferList,bool overwrite=true)
        {

            for (int index = 0; index < fileTransferList.Count; index++)
            {
                FileTransferData file = fileTransferList[index];
                outputter.display(index + "/" + fileTransferList.Count + ": " + file.sourcePath);
                //do some file conversion operations
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
```

When `convertFiles()` is running, the label gets updated with the first call to `outputter.display()`, but then the app just freezes with the blue busy circle until it's finished with the For loop.  The For loop successfully writes to the output device with the `outputter.display()` calls when I implement the `IOutputter.display()` method using `Console.WriteLine()`.  I want the text in the label to refresh every time the For loop iterates; is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Perhaps use a threaded worker with events? - problem is without a separate thread, your worker thread and form thread are the same - meaning there is no time for it to reach refresh() while the worker method is so busy.

Comment: You're doing the work on the UI thread which is why it freezes because it's busy. Do the work on something other than the UI thread. If you're a beginner then [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) is an easy way to do this.

Comment: And if someone suggests using `Application.DoEvents()` just don't...

Comment: Why not @MatthewWatson? It works and is easy :)

Comment: A kitten dies every time `DoEvents` is used, two kittens die when it's inside a `while` loop.

Comment: @Pikoh Plenty of things in life are easy, doesn't mean they're right.

Comment: Just tying to be sarcastic @Equalsk :)

Comment: You forgot your /s ;-)

Comment: @Equalsk, I'm not sure how to apply BackgroundWorker in this situation.  It seems I need to call `BatchConverter.convertFiles()` inside `backgroundWorker_DoWork`, but then how do I call the `backgroundWorker_ReportProgress` event inside `convertFiles()`?  If I put all the code from `convertFiles()` in the `DoWork` event handler, then it violates information hiding, and also makes that code unavailable for other UIs (say I want to run it from the console).  Sorry if I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: The [accepted answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker) should give you a fair idea. Make the background worker have a scope that `convertFiles` can see to call `ReportProgress`.