# frequency of data logging in C#

Tags: c#

Dear users & developers,

I have a C# code that writes a variable to a file everytime it changes in value. I want to change it so that it can write every 1 minute (another input to be specified by the user) or so from the time it starts. I am new to data logging, any help/insights regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
AK

Comment: Do you know what a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.1) is?

Comment: What kind of application it is? Web application or Windows form application ?

Comment: Hi Chetan, Its a windows form application

Answer (score 0):

My first tought is to maybe use a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` running in the background:

```
// This is a very crude implementation, but it should serve its purpose.
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class App
{
    public bool isAppActive = true;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task mytsk = MyLog();
        Console.ReadKey();
        isAppActive = false;
    }

    public static async void MyLog()
    {
        while (App.isAppActive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            // Write your variable to a file (using an async method and await)
        }
    }
}
```

... Or maybe using a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker).