# System.InvalidOperationException error when populating an array

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

So I have a program that works as the UI for a console app. I tried to add a progress bar to it. When the user clicks on the `Start` button, it does this:

```
MainProgress.Value = 0;
MainProgress.Maximum = PackageNwCheckbox.IsChecked == true ? 4 : 3;
BackgroundWorker compilerWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
compilerWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
compilerWorker.DoWork += StartCompiler;
compilerWorker.ProgressChanged += CompilerReport;
compilerWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This is in order to update the progress bar when the GUI program works and feeds the console program. When the program starts populating the array called `filemap` like this:

```
filemap = Directory.GetFiles(ProjectLocation.Text + "\\www\\js\\", "*.js");
//The variable is an array of strings.
```

The app crashes and the error says

> The call thread couldn't access the item because another thread has it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Comment: Since you are using the `BackgroundWorker` you'll want to only interact with the UI elements from your CompilerReport method, or you'll need to pass the object value in the `RunWorkerAsync()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481328/252458 for a bit more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `ProjectLocation.Text` from a background thread. You can only access members of a UI control on the thread on which it was originally created.

So if you want the current text of `ProjectLocation` in your `DoWork` event handler, you should use the dispatcher:

```
string location = Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ProjectLocation.Text);
filemap = Directory.GetFiles(location + "\\www\\js\\", "*.js");
```

Or pass it as an argument to the `RunWorkerAsync` method.

Answer (score 1):

In desktop applications with background threads, if you're attempting to update a view. You will need to invoke that update with the dispatcher. Somewhere in your `CompilerReport` method you want something like this:

```
MainProgress.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // Do update here
});
```

With more code, I could probably detail a better answer