# How to call a controller action method again and again in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not that much efficient in mvc. I want to continuously try pinging the IPs in the list and then render the data in Index view using Viewbag. but problem here is I have to refresh the page manually each and every time to get the current status of each and every IP.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<string> IPlist = new List<string>();
            IPlist.Add("10.0.1.151");
            IPlist.Add("www.google.com");
            IPlist.Add("192.168.0.1");
            Ping myping = new Ping();
            StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder("Ping Status:");
            foreach (string c in IPlist)
            {
                PingReply replytest = myping.Send(c, 1000);

                if (replytest != null)
                {
                    sc.Append(" Status : " + replytest.Status + " \n Time: " + replytest.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " \n Address : " + replytest.Address + " \n ");
                }
                else
                {
                    sc.Append("Request Failed");
                }
            }

            ViewBag.result = sc.ToString();

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use a`BackgroundWorker`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker

Comment: You can create new `action` which would return only your desired `string`. Call this `action` with `ajax` on some `interval` and update your DOM with `javascript`.

Comment: @karan can you please elaborate a little please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new `action` which return a `JsonResult` from a controller to the ajax query. Simply convert the string to `JsonResult` by using `Json(stringvalue)`;

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult GetCurrentStatus()
    {
        List<string> IPlist = new List<string>();
        IPlist.Add("10.0.1.151");
        IPlist.Add("www.google.com");
        IPlist.Add("192.168.0.1");
        Ping myping = new Ping();
        StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder("Ping Status:");
        foreach (string c in IPlist)
        {
            PingReply replytest = myping.Send(c, 1000);

            if (replytest != null)
            {
                sc.Append(" Status : " + replytest.Status + " \n Time: " + replytest.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " \n Address : " + replytest.Address + " \n ");
            }
            else
            {
                sc.Append("Request Failed");
            }
        }
        
        return Json(sc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Add `javascript` `function` which call new `action`. And call this function every `5000 milliseconds` with `setInterval`. On `success` of `ajax` I am setting `retrieved` value to
element with id `divPintStatus`. You can change it as per your actual code. Also set `@Url.Action` as your own code.

```
setInterval(getCurrentStatus, 5000);

function getCurrentStatus() {
    $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentStatus")',    // Or '@Url.Action("GetCurrentStatus", "ControllerName")',
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json",
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         success: function (data) {
            $('#divPintStatus').val(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked for me with a little modifications... Thanks.. @karan