# Running timer immediately in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a windows service on VS.net C#

In the OnStart event I start a timer.

In side the timer I call a function called DO()

the process of the DO() function is very long ( takes more than hour)

The process suppose to go this way

Start Then call the time immediately but due to the timer interval need to wait another day

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart.");

    try
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 *60 * 24;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
        DO();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("ERROR (OnStart) : " + ex.ToString());

    }
}

    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        DO();
    }

    private void DO()
    {
     // Some process takes an hour
    }
```

When the service starts it stays an hour in "Starting"

Is there a way I can start my service DO() function immediatly once the service started but not from the OnStart event?

[image]

Comment: Regarding Windows Services in general, when starting if your code takes too long Windows Service Manager marks your service as _unresponsive_.  For this reason `OnStart()` and more importantly `Do()` should not carryout _"Some process takes an hour"_.  `OnStart` should perform minimal work and spawn child threads as necessary.  Also you should look into setting your Service State. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-status-transitions

Comment: yes, use a BackgroundWorker, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker

Comment: ...and to fix the _"Starting"_ problem, simply remove the call to `DO()` in your `OnStart`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you left nothing out of your example, your timer elapsed method will run on the `ThreadPool`.

So I would change this line in `OnStart`

```
DO();
```

...with this line:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => Do());
```

It has the same net effect of what would happen if the timer fired immediately and, more importantly, will not block on that line.

Comment: Will the thread stop when I stop the service?

Comment: @asmgx Yes, because thread pool threads are background threads.

Comment: @asmgx whenever a process exits all file handles and threads are closed

Comment: @MickyD No.  Foreground threads will prevent a process from closing.  See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Comment: @Zer0 I said when the _"process exits"_.  If it is exiting, any prior foreground threads have already exited.  Additionally a Windows Service has no primary thread by default

Comment: @MickyD You did and I agree.  But if you try to stop a service with a foreground thread running it will not stop.  A simple `new Thread()` will create a foreground thread, even in a service.  Basically I wanted to clarify why this is safe, as opposed to spinning up your own `Thread`.  I'm aware you can set `IsBackground` on a `Thread`, however we both know this is a common bug that prevents processes from exiting gracefully.

Comment: after experment, thread still running even after uninstalling the service

Comment: @asmgx I would need to know the code in `DO`.  I just tested that stopping a service with only background threads works fine.  However, you're bringing up a different question entirely.  Might need to find/ask a different question about stopping services.  You can test anywhere in the code with `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground`.  Anything that returns false can prevent the service from stopping.