# Using while loop in a command freezes window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a button that executes a command, and it contains a while loop, the application freezes after I start the command, I have also tried to run it recursively but I got the same behavior, and using a timer is not an option, the task can't be called using an interval

Comment: In the future, post the relevant code when asking a question

Comment: You can use Background worker and show progress bar on UI.
Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the blocking section of your code in a separate thread. Running it on the main UI thread will freeze the UI.

You can use `Tasks` to do this.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

```
Task.Run(() => {
    while (condition)
    {
        // operation
    }
});
```

Comment: A background thread is not always the best or correct solution. It really depends on the actual code that is blocking. For example, using an async API would provide better performance.